# How do I make this search bar on top of an image like this

Tags: flutter, dart

I was looking at the BlaBlaCar mobile app and wanted to replicate their homepage for my flutter app so how could I make it like the image attached[image: BlaBlaCar homepage]

I added a column with a container with a defined height and used stack but it's not working

````
Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .8,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("images/background.jpg"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
          children: [searchBar()],
        )
      ],
    ));```
````

Comment: Are you having difficulty on positioning `searchBar()`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try make use of a SliverAppBar (pop the code into dartpad)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const AppBarApp());

class AppBarApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppBarApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: SliverAppBarExample(),
    );
  }
}

class SliverAppBarExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const SliverAppBarExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<SliverAppBarExample> createState() => _SliverAppBarExampleState();
}

class _SliverAppBarExampleState extends State<SliverAppBarExample> {
// [SliverAppBar]s are typically used in [CustomScrollView.slivers], which in
// turn can be placed in a [Scaffold.body].
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            bottom: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(AppBar().preferredSize.height),
              child: Container(height: 200, width: 400, color: Colors.red),
            ),
            collapsedHeight: 200,
            expandedHeight: 400,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              background: SizedBox(
                height: 400,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(color: Colors.yellow),
                    ),
                    Container(color: Colors.white, height: 100),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  height: 100.0,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('$index', textScaleFactor: 5),
                  ),
                );
              },
              childCount: 20,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]